# Find parametrization for a possible "ruled" surface in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let us endow $\mathbb R^4$ with a group law $\cdot$ such that the dilations $\delta_\lambda:(\mathbb R^4,\cdot)\to (\mathbb R^4,\cdot), (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto (\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2,\lambda^2 x_3,\lambda^3 x_4)$, are automorphisms of the group for each $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Now, let $S\subseteq \mathbb R^4$ be an hypersurface given by $$S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb R^4: f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):=\frac{1}{6}x_2(x_1^2+x_2^2)-\frac{1}{2}x_1 x_3+x_4=0\}.$$

It is easy to see that $S$ is dilation invariant, i.e. $\delta_\lambda(S)=S \,\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R$. Since $S$ has this property, I was trying to see if it is possible to write $S$ as a "ruled" surface, that is writing it with a parametric representation of the form $$S(u_1,u_2,u_3)=p(u_1,u_2)+u_3 r(u_1,u_2) \quad (*).$$
The important thing here is that we have to remember that the dilations we are working with aren't the usual Euclidean ones, so we would like that the parametric representation of $S$ had the following property: for each fixed $(u_1,u_2)$, $u_3\mapsto u_3 r(u_1,u_2)$ is a line which is a subgroup of $(\mathbb R^4,\cdot)$ and it is invariant under dilations of the group, that is the image of $u_3\mapsto u_3 r(u_1,u_2)$ is $\delta_\lambda$-homogeneous subgroup of topological dimension 1.

Now, we know that the only $\delta_\lambda$-homogeneous subgroup of topological dimension 1 in $(\mathbb R^4,\cdot,\delta_\lambda)$ are of the form:

- $\{(\alpha t,\beta t,0,0):t\in \mathbb R\}, \alpha,\beta$ fixed;
- $\{(0,0, t,0):t\in \mathbb R\}$;
- $\{(0,0,0,t):t\in \mathbb R\}$.

My question is: is it possible to find a parametric representation of $S$ of this form? I've tried to write $S$ as the image of $$(s_1,s_2,s_3)\mapsto (s_1,s_2,s_3,-\frac{1}{6}s_2(s_1^2+s_2^2)+\frac{1}{2}s_1 s_3),$$ but it doesn't seem possible to manipulate this parametrization in order to obtain a parametric representation of the form $(*).$ Am I wrong? Also, one can explicit $x_3$ in function of the other variables, but also using the parametrization with $x_3$ explicit I can't arrive to an expression of the form $(*)$.

Do you see a way to manage this problem? Or do you think it is not possible to do something like that?

Comment: To clarify: The orbits of your group action are twisted cubics. If I understand your goal, you want to write your surface as a union of rulings, i.e., _group orbits_; is that right?

Comment: I'm quite new on this kind of argument, so I'm not familiar with group orbits and group action.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand your goal, but this is too long for a comment.

For each $(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4})$, the curve
$$
\lambda \mapsto (\lambda x_{1}, \lambda x_{2}, \lambda^{2} x_{3}, \lambda^{3} x_{4})
\tag{1}
$$
is a twisted cubic transverse to each of the hyperplanes $\{x_{i} = 1\}$. The hypersurface $S$ may therefore be parametrized by parametrizing the $2$-dimensional intersection $S \cap \{x_{i} = 1\}$ (for any convenient $i$), and then using $\lambda$ in (1) as third parameter.

For example, the surface $S \cap \{x_{3} = 1\}$, which has equation
$$
\tfrac{1}{6} x_{2}(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}) - \tfrac{1}{2} x_{1} + x_{4} = 0,
$$
may be parametrized by
$$
(u_{1}, u_{2}) \mapsto \bigl[u_{1}, u_{2}, 1, \tfrac{1}{2} u_{1} - \tfrac{1}{6} u_{2}(u_{1}^{2} + u_{2}^{2})\bigr].
$$
The hypersurface $S$ may therefore be parametrized by
$$
(u_{1}, u_{2}, \lambda) \mapsto \bigl[\lambda u_{1}, \lambda u_{2}, \lambda^{2}, \lambda^{3}\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2} u_{1} - \tfrac{1}{6} u_{2}(u_{1}^{2} + u_{2}^{2})\bigr)\bigr].
$$
Is this the type of parametrization you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm not sure that you can describe the whole hypersurface $S$ using this parametrization, because for example it doesn't take into account points with $x_3<0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, I was looking for writing the surface as union of *particular* group orbits. The orbits I would like to use are $\delta_\lambda$-homogeneous lines, those I've written in the question.

Comment: You're right that my proposed parametrization doesn't cover all of $S$; on that subject, is your group action the multiplicative group of _positive_ reals? As written, $\delta_{\lambda}$ seems not to be a group action. Separately, I'm still not completely clear about the constraint of using line orbits. All $\delta_{\lambda}$-homogeneous lines lie on a coordinate axis or plane; a "linear combination" from these lines is no longer $\delta_{\lambda}$-homogeneous. Can give a two- or three-dimensional example of what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps? :)

Comment: I don't know an example in 2 o 3 dimensions, I have to think about it. Then, I think this is a group action for each $\lambda$.

Comment: Perhaps something like $\delta_{\lambda}(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) = (\lambda x_{1}, \lambda x_{2}, \lambda^{2} x_{3})$ and $S$ defined by $x_{2}(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}) - x_{1} x_{3} = 0$? (Regarding the group action, it seems you want to take $\lambda$ to be an arbitrary real number (including zero), but the operation is multiplication...?)

Comment: I want to take all real number for $\lambda$. What operation are you talking about? The operation on $\mathbb R^4$ or the operation on the $\delta_\lambda$? In the first case the operation is not multiplication, in the second case, I think -since I'm not so sure about group actions and things like that- we can endow $\{\delta_\lambda\}_\lambda$ with a group structure such that $\delta_\mu \delta_\lambda=\delta_{\lambda \mu}$. I hope I've answered to your question, but I'm not sure about this last thing.

Comment: I was asking about the group operation on the $\delta_{\lambda}$. Because $\delta_{\lambda}$ acts by multiplication by powers of $\lambda$, the natural guess is that $\lambda$ is either positive (in which case $\lambda = e^{t}$ for some real $t$) or at least non-zero. You can allow $\lambda = 0$ in your equations, but only at the cost of not having a group (since $0$ isn't multiplicatively invertible).

Comment: Ok, I see. Well the dilations make sense for each $\lambda\in \mathbb R$.  But why are you so interested in seeing the dilations as group actions? I'm sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: Still trying to clarify your goal in my mind. I had understood you wanted to parametrize (part or all of) $S$ as a union of "orbits" (curves along which $\lambda$ is a parameter), analogously to a ruled surface. But then, the action of $\delta_{\lambda}$ seems peculiar for a couple of technical reasons.... I'm happy to leave my post for posterity and the benefit of a possible future respondent, or to delete it if I'm just muddying the waters. Either way, it might help others if you add to the question some information about where the problem comes from. :)

Comment: Ok, thank you again for your help. The thing is that I don't think that adding information about where the problem comes from may help other respondent, just because I'm interested in studying the hypersurface $S$ in order to see if it has some nice properties. But maybe I can try to modify the post in order to make it clearer.